# Deploying to GCP: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

Receiving the error above when deploying a python app to a Docker image on GCP.

My cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
  # Install dependencies
  - name: python
    entrypoint: pip
    args: ["install", "-r", "requirements.txt", "--user"]

# Docker Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 
          'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO}/myimage:123', '.']

  # Docker push to Google Artifact Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push',  'us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO}/bpids:${SHORT_SHA}']

# Store images in Google Artifact Registry 
images:
  - us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO}/bpids:${SHORT_SHA}
```

The terminal command I'm invoking:

> gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml
> --substitutions=_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO=bpids

Step 0 works correctly and loads all the requirements.

Step 1 exits with the following:

Finished Step #0

Starting Step #1

Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker

Step #1: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat
/workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Finished Step #1

ERROR

ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero
status: 1

Comment: You have a missing file problem. Include the Dockerfile in your post. Are you using ignore files such as `.gcloudignore`?